# how can be select mini date (1 april ) financial date in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, laravel, datepicker

I want to select min date as 1st april 2018 and max date to current date
i have already tried these:

```
$("#primarySaleDatePicker").pickadate({
        min: 1 april,
        max: 'today',
        closeOnSelect: true,
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        onSet: function (ele) {
         if(ele.select){
          this.close();
        }
      }
```

Comment: http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/ do tell you `min: new Date(2015,3,20)`. Try to give a `Date` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set like this: https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/PaLyaJ

```
$("#primarySaleDatePicker").pickadate({
        min: new Date(2018,3,01),
        max: 'today',
        closeOnSelect: true,
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        onSet: function (ele) {
         if(ele.select){
          this.close();
        }
      }
})
```